# echarts: focus node adjacency in graph on click

Tags: echarts

In past echarts versions where was a `focusNodeAdjacency` action which allowed to focus on a node in a graph.
In newer versions this action is removed, and I can't seem to find anything that replaces it with the same functionality. `Highlight` comes close but does not function like I want.

Is there any way around this? I would like to make only a node and its neighbors be visible on click on the node.

Comment: can you specify what is `past version`? Which version you are currently using and refering your question to?

Comment: @thowa It's in the v4 documentation: https://echarts.apache.org/v4/en/api.html#action.graph.focusNodeAdjacency, currently using 5.3.2 and it seems to be removed.